# How can I get the input changed value when onClick2 is pressed in onClick3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

onClick2 causes the state to receive the changed value.

However, onClick3 wants to deliver the changed state value only when onClick2 is pressed.

How can I control the changed value of the input?

When onClick3 is pressed when the input value is changed to 456
Is it possible to get the previous value of onChange ?

my code...

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("123");

  const onChangeInput = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const onClick2 = () => {
    console.log(value);
  };

  const onClick3 = () => {
    // how to onclick2 preve
    console.log(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={onChangeInput} value={value} />
      <button onClick={onClick2}>Button1</button>
      <button onClick={onClick3}>Button2</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 2 useState one for prevValue and one for currentValue like this-

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("123")
const [prevValue, setPrevValue] = useState(value)

const onChangeInput = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
}

const onClick2 = () => {
    setPrevValue(value)
}

const onClick3 = () => {
    console.log('Previous : ', prevValue)
    console.log('Current : ', value)
}
```

When you click on onClick2 btn it will update previous Value and when you click on onClick3 btn it will give you output as previous and updated Values.

```
# If your current value is 456

output: 
    Previous : 123
    Current : 456
```

Just add this code and you will get your answer.